# Autocompletetextview android with any suggestion

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Sorry, I'm newbie

please help how to use AutoCompleteTextView any suggestions with one link in all words ?

example:

1. United States (US) if typing US or United States it will bring suggestions
2. United Kingdom (UK) if typing UK or United Kingdom it will bring suggestions

Answer (score 0):

AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_textview);

```
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7" };

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    list.add(values[i]);
}
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);

actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                adapter.getItem(position).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```